# Passing form button data

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I wondered, how to pass some kind of data from form button (id, or anything else) to use it in if statement, to regulate what form elements are showing.

Can i pass ID some how, can't seem to find documentation about this, and i dont want to use javaScript so much.

```
{{Form::button('Change form data', ['id'=>"izvele",'class' => 'btn btn-success'])}} 
        @if(?????????????)
        @endif
```

Comment: Give it a `name="something"` tag, it will then appear in the submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this,

```
if (request()->has('izvele')) {
...
}
```

but only after submitting the form.

Comment: Ye, that will not help. I need to change forms layout befor submiting it